# Django : Invalid block tag on line 121: 'popular_products', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, templatetags

I have a custom template tag in my project and every thing looks fine but when i want to use this template tag i got this error:

Invalid block tag on line 122: 'popular_products', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

base_tags.py:

```
from django import template
from django.db.models import Count, Q
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from shop.models import Product

register = template.Library()


@register.inclusion_tag('shared/partials/popular_product_slider.html')
def popular_products():
    last_week = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=7)
    return {
        "popular_products": Product.objects.filter(available=True).annotate(
            count=Count('hits', filter=Q(producthit__date__gt=last_week))).order_by(
            '-count', '-created')[:3]
    }
```

home_page.html template:

```
 {% extends 'shared/_base.html' %}
 {% load base_tags %}
 {% load i18n %}
 {% load render_partial %}
 {% load static %}
 {% load ratings %}
 {% load thumbnail %}

 {% block content %}
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
         <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="recent" class="tab-pane fade show active">
                <div class="row  product-slider">
                        {% popular_products %}
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
  </div>
 </div>
{% endblock %}
```

popular_product_slider.html

```
{% for product in popular_products %}
    {{product.image}}
    {{product.detail}}
    {{product.title}}
{% endfor %}
```

views.py

```
def home_page(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'Home_page.html', context)
```

Comment: I deleted my templatetags and make it again and now every thing works fine, i think it was an Idle bug or something

Answer (score 0):

you need to place your code in home_page.html in block. xxx is the name of block that you placed in _base.html

```
{% block xxx %}
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-12">
           <div class="tab-content">
               <div id="recent" class="tab-pane fade show active">
                   <div class="row  product-slider">
                        {% popular_products %}
                   </div>
               </div>
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have wrongly used `{% popular_products %}`. You should use `{% include 'popular_product_slider.html' %}` to implement `popular_product_slider.html` into `home_page.html`.

If you use curly template brackets with precentage sign (`{% %}`), then first value is taken as a command. And file didn't recognize `popular_products` as command and it raises `Error`.

Comment: Yes, i use content block in my template end it is exactly like this but i just forget to add it to question,so this is not the problem

Comment: @MatinNajafi I've edited my answer. `{% popular_products %}` is the reason it's not working properly.